# SQL - Date field restriction (<=today)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table with date which is entered when the member joins the club. The column is bog standard with DATE as type. No need to have time.

Basically I am trying to find a way that it can not be in the future?

Comment: you should compare it to the return of NOW()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers. Below is a fully-functional tested example:

```
create table t(signup_date date not null);

delimiter //
create trigger ins_check_date before insert on t
  for each row
  begin
    if (new.signup_date > current_date()) then
      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Date cannot be in the future';
    end if;
  end//

create trigger up_check_date before update on t
  for each row
  begin
    if (new.signup_date > current_date()) then
      signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Date cannot be in the future';
    end if;
  end//



delimiter ;

insert into t values (current_date());
insert into t values (current_date() - interval 1 day);
insert into t values (current_date() - interval 2 day);
insert into t values (current_date() + interval 1 day);

select * from t;
update t set signup_date = signup_date - interval 1 month 
where signup_date = current_date() - interval 1 day;

update t set signup_date = signup_date + interval 1 month 
where signup_date = current_date();
select * from t;
```